# How to use pagination with get_post_meta

Tags: custom-field, pagination, post-meta

I have a Products Page that i am using to add products using custom metaboxes this is the code for my page

```
<div class="container products">

    <div class="row">

      <?php
        $count = (int)1;
        $products = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_cmb2_repeat_group', true );

        foreach ( (array) $products as $key => $product ) {

            $img = $title = $desc = '';

            if ( isset( $product['product_name'] ) )
                $title = esc_html( $product['product_name'] );

            if ( isset( $product['product_description'] ) )
                $desc = wpautop( $product['product_description'] );
                $caption = wp_trim_words( $desc, 55, ' &hellip;' );


            if ( isset( $product['product_image_id'] ) ) {            
                $img = wp_get_attachment_image( $product['product_image_id'], 'product', null, array(
                  'class' => 'img-thumbnail',
              ) );
            }


        if($count&1){
          $span = 'col-xs-5 ' . 'col-sm-4 ' . 'col-sm-offset-1 ';
        }
        else{
          $span = 'col-xs-5 ' . 'col-xs-offset-2 ' . 'col-sm-4 ' . 'col-sm-offset-2 ';
        }
        $count++;

      ?>
      <div class="<?php echo $span; ?>box">
        <a href="#">
          <?php echo $img; ?>
          <span class="rotate-caption hidden-xs">
            <h3><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
            <hr>
            <p><?php echo $caption; ?></p>
          </span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>

  </div>
```

i want to use pagination on this page so it displays 6 entries per page , i tried searching on wordpress pagination but i can't figure out how to use it with custom metabox , in the codex it is used with $wp_query and i can't understand how to exactly make it work in my case with custom fields. Thanks in advance

UPDATE : here is the code for the metabox itself

```
$meta_boxes['field_group'] = array(
    'id'           => 'field_group',
    'title'        => __( 'Manage your products here', 'cmb2' ),
    'show_on'      => array( 'id' => array( 11, ) ), // Specific post IDs to display this metabox
    'object_types' => array( 'page', ),
    'fields'       => array(
        array(
            'id'          => $prefix . 'repeat_group',
            'type'        => 'group',
            'options'     => array(
                'group_title'   => __( 'Product {#}', 'cmb2' ), // {#} gets replaced by row number
                'add_button'    => __( 'Add Another Product', 'cmb2' ),
                'remove_button' => __( 'Remove Product', 'cmb2' ),
                'sortable'      => true, // beta
            ),
            'fields'      => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'Product Name',
                    'id'   => 'product_name',
                    'type' => 'text',
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'Product Description',
                    'description' => 'Write a short description for this Product',
                    'id'   => 'product_description',
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'Product Image',
                    'id'   => 'product_image',
                    'type' => 'file',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Just so it's clear, you are trying to paginate custom field values on a single post, displaying 6 values per page?

Comment: Where is these metaboxes?

Comment: @PieterGoosen edited the post ive added the metabox code, i just want to ensure you that it is displayed on the frontend just fine my issue how is how to add pagination support to this

Comment: @jdm2112 thanks for following on , as you can see it is a group field i have created using https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress/wiki/Field-Types#group , so once the client wants to add new product he will have 3 fields to complete image , name and description .. like you have said i want the pagination to display 6 entries per page

Comment: I don't understand, are you adding these on a single post. What I understand is that you are adding an unlimited amount of info in a single post? Am I right.

Comment: @PieterGoosen yes you are right , it is considered unlimited . if the client added 100 products i will have 100 products displayed on the page this is why i want to use pagination ... i am new to wordpress and i think i have made a mistake here by adding this metabox to page not a post , i should have made custom post type from the very begining , it make more sense to have a post_type=>'post' not a page here  am i right ?

Comment: I don't get you on this. 1product = 1page or 100products = 1 page, and you are correct, you should have used `post` post type or a custom post type, not page. There are plugins available that can switch post types

Comment: @PieterGoosen sorry if i am not able to explain it check out this link this is a static version of the site , it may help    http://tents.byethost8.com/products.html ... i need pagination here to make sure products page always displaying 6 items no more

Comment: products should be a post type, not meta data on a page. you've severely limited your capabilities adding them as meta data, and you're going to write a lot of code you would get for free if you simply switched to using a post type instead.

Comment: @Milo  true i have realized that , i am thinking to start over on this product page to make thing bit more easy , thanks for replying.

Comment: I really do agree with @Milo and I would also suggest to rethink your complete structure and start over.

Comment: i am already on the track for restructure , thanks everyone for your help , great community!